# $interval not working when set in AngularJS Controller

Tags: angularjs, setinterval

I've checked out other questions on here and they didn't have the answer.

I have the following: (excerpt)

```
    ...
    $scope.direction = 'left';
    $scope.currentSlideIndex = 0;

    $scope.nextSlide = function () {
        $scope.direction = 'left';
        $scope.currentSlideIndex = ($scope.currentSlideIndex < $scope.slides.length - 1) ? ++$scope.currentSlideIndex : 0;
    };

    $interval($scope.nextSlide, 4000);
    ...
```

and nothing happens. I've injected $interval. No Console error messages. I know the function itself works since when it gets called with ng-click, it works fine.

Potential issue: I have a newsfeed scrolling on the same page. Could the underlying interval of that newsfeed be killing this one? That's getting its movement from an outside script and I'm having a hard time nailing it down to stop it to check.

Comment: Are you certain it's not firing?  Have you tried console logging to see?  The call looks fine from what I can see.

Comment: Yup. I put an alert in the function and nada.

Comment: When is the `$interval($scope.nextSlide, 4000);` setup being done?  Is that after an ng-click or after the page finishes loading?

Comment: It's in my controller, right after the functions are defined. However, I also put it in my script.js, thinking maybe it wasn't firing initially, but that didn't work either. How can I make sure it's called on the page load?

Comment: Personally, I've never placed an $interval call directly in the controller.  I usually wrap that sort of stuff in an init method.  `$scope.init();` in the controller and then call `$interval` within `$scope.init = function() {}`.  Maybe give that a try.

Comment: I just tried:`$scope.init = function() {$interval($scope.nextSlide, 4000);};` and it didn't work. I put that in the controller as well.

Comment: I even put an alert in the init to make sure it was called, and it was. The $interval wasn't, though.

Comment: Hmm, I just tried it a different way and it looks like the interval IS actually working now, but it's changing $scope variables, and alerts confirm this, but those variables aren't changing where they're bound on the page so the slides aren't moving. It also only cycles through 3 times (the length of the slides array) then stops. Odd.

Comment: Ok, so I got the whole thing working, but it only cycles through the length of the slides array once. The line of code should reset it to 0 and keep it going, but it's not: `$scope.currentSlideIndex = ($scope.currentSlideIndex < $scope.slides.length - 1) ? ++$scope.currentSlideIndex : 0;` Thoughts?

Comment: Maybe if you can share more of your code it would help.  I'm at a loss at this point.

Answer (score 0):

May this example will helpful for you.

```
var myapp = angular.module("myapp", []);
    myapp.controller("MyController", *function($scope, $interval)*{
        $interval(callAtInterval, 5000);
    });
    function callAtInterval() {
        console.log("Interval occurred");
    }
```

Try above code.

Comment: Wait a second. In my example, both the function and the interval call are in the controller. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Here in my code inject $interval at controller declaration. Like $score keyword.

Comment: okay, may you have to define function with specific name like "function callAtInterval()".

Comment: May I see your controller.js file?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. As I mentioned, there's a news feed on the site as well. There was code in there that was killing all intervals and restarting the one I wanted. That was happening on the 3.5 second mark. I cleaned that all up, set up the intervals properly and I have both running fine now.

Thanks all for your help! :-)